# VBA code issue to search records. run time error 424 object required

Tags: excel, vba

I have an issue with the searching record from the sheet and displayed on textbox or Combobox but getting an error as run time error 424 objects required. Could you please help me with this.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long
    x = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Products").Range("A" & Row.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For y = 2 To x
        If Sheets("Products").Cells(y, "A").Text = TextBox11.Text Then
            TextBox1.Text = Sheet2.Cells(y, "B")
            TextBox2.Text = Sheet2.Cells(y, "C")
        end if
    next y
end sub
```

Comment: On which line does the error occur?  This error usually means that _something_ you are trying to use in your code doesn't actually exist

Comment: Where are `TextBox11`, `TextBox1`, and `TextBox2` **Dimmed** and **Set** ???

Comment: you might try : `Me!TextBox1.Text` if the textBox are on the same userform than the code. Else if they are on a different userform you might try : `userformname.TextBox1.Text`

Comment: I'm getting an error on **x = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Products").Range("A" & Row.Count).End(xlUp).Row**  **Textbox11** is search box and **textbox1** and **textbox2** will display result from sheet colomn b and c.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `Rows.Count`...

```
x = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Products").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Although, you should qualify your reference to `Rows`...

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Products")
    x = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

Comment: Hi, Domenic Thank you so so much. There was issue of just  **row** to **rows**. Thanks, buddy to save my time. It already has taken too much time to understand.